# how to read all files in a directory in python with Visual Studio compile

Tags: python, file, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, glob

I have the following code that should read all the .txt files in the folder where my project is located (I'm doing it in Visual Studio Code):

```
for file in glob.glob("*.txt"):
    fp = open(file, "r", -1, 'utf-8')
    text= fp.readlines()
    print(file, "->", text)
```

I would like to read all the files (without informing the directories) .txt that are in my folder but this function is somehow not working in Visual Studio, but it works perfectly in Jupyter notebook.

Output/Content of the `text` variable in jupyter notebook

```
file1.txt -> ["this phrase is in file 1"]
file2.txt -> ["this phrase is in file 2"]
file3.txt -> ["this phrase is in file 3"]
```

Does anyone know if I'm forgetting a Visual Studio function or configuration or is there another function that does this?

Comment: It depends on where the default file path is set

Comment: glob's function is to obtain the file listing of the directory where the project is located, there is no need for a standard path in this case

Comment: Can you verify in VS that the program is reading files from that folder by printing current working directory?
`import os

print(os.getcwd())`

Comment: @simonica and if that was the case, `print(glob.glob("*.txt"))` would have just listed every single file on my Windows system with a `.txt` extension, right? It gives an empty list. You're asserting something without even considering the issue

Comment: I've just been playing with Spyder and I can get `glob.glob` to list the files I want in any working directory I have, regardless of the folder that script is in.

Comment: If you do not add a path to that glob specification, it uses *whatever* the "current working directory" is. If you print it out from within that same script, you may find out that your two attempts run in different folders than you think they do. To make sure it works the same, add the full path in the glob function.

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with VS but it sounds like your VS project is created in a different directory from where the files are. and Jupyter is in the same directory.

Comment: no, the files are all in the same folder, both the jupyter project files and the VS code project